# Some Libre Office menu items are always hidden

Tags: libreoffice, menu

In LibreOffice, why can't you open the full menu list? Always looks like this:

[image]

But I want to see the full list of menu items, without having to scroll down to reach the bottom items.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is a confirmed [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1024292). I wasn't able to reproduce it under Ubuntu 12.10, so if you are using a previous release and upgrading is viable, it is probably worth giving it a try.